# how to create login form using sqlite in iphone view based application?

Tags: iphone

i want to create login form using sqlite in iphone view based application please help me.give any idea about sqlite in iphone and any sqlite tutorial for iphone application development..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this [tutorial](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

very nice tutorial,

Just FYI, I recommend using [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817/) to edit SQLite. 
It is much faster in real life.

Thankz